# opening Internet Explorer using c programming language

Tags: c

I made a c program in which I used the very notorious system () function to open internet explorer.There was no error as I compiled it but it is giving me output as illegal command. What is the problem?? I have rechecked my Internet Explorer address in c drive but everything is perfect. how to solve this?

Comment: Did you check permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have specified the path to Internet Explorer like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

But because the `\` character is an "escape" character in a literal string, you need to defeat the escape

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"
```

There was no error when you compiled because the compiler cannot check whether the command passed to `system()` will be meaningful, or valid at runtime.